# Twitter Bootstrap: Call a js function when a dropdown is closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events

Is there an event that I can tie into that is fired when a bootstrap dropdown is closed or toggled?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the end, the only reliable method that I found was to use jquery's data api to store the state of the dropdown and add click events to the button and the document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#dropdown').data('open', false);

    $('#dropdown-button').click(function() {
        if($('#dropdown').data('open')) {
            $('#dropdown').data('open', false);
            update_something();
        } else
            $('#dropdown').data('open', true);
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        if($('#dropdown').data('open')) {
            $('#dropdown').data('open', false);
            update_something();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, great approach. Thanks Nolan

Comment: In addition you can fake the bootstrap 3 events by replacing update_something(); with: `$('#dropdown').trigger('hide.bs.dropdown')`;

That way when you upgrade you can rip it out and keep going.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are two dropdowns, and one is clicked when the other is open.

Answer (score 44):

From [twitter bootstrap official page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns):

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

`hide.bs.dropdown` is [one of 4 events described here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events).

#### Update (13-Apr-16)

These events also work same in `Bootstrap 4`. [Bootstrap v4 Documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#events).

Answer (score 27):

This is how Bootstrap v2.3.2 closes the menu no matter what you click on:

```
$('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
    $el.parent().removeClass('open')
});
```

If you're using v2.x, this could be used to know when a menu will be closed. However, keep in mind that this is triggered on every click. If you only need to execute something when a menu is really closed (which is probably all the time), you'll need to track when one is opened in the first place. The accepted answer is probably a better solution in that regard.

In Boostrap v3.0.0, however, the drop menu supports four separate events:

> **show.bs.dropdown**: This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
>
> **shown.bs.dropdown** This event is fired when the dropdown has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).
>
> **hide.bs.dropdown** This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called.
>
> **hidden.bs.dropdown** This event is fired when the dropdown has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions, to complete).

From [Bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage).

Comment: thanks! this helped me to detect that my dropdown-menu has been closed by clicking outside its borders!

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a documented event, but you can use the `.open` class of the `.dropdown` and the jQuery `click()` event:

```
$('#the-dropdown').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        alert('it works');
    }
});
```

For toggling, use just the `click()` event.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/simbirsk/cWkXK/1/) is the jsfiddle.

Comment: The problem is that I need it to trigger anytime it closes, not just when the button is pressed.

Comment: @albertedevigo works great, but how do I get at the contents of the item (a list item), so I can use it?

Comment: @mark1234 you should ask a new question providing some code.

Answer (score 2):

Nolan, I assume what you mean by "This did not work" is: when the user clicks anywhere else on the page and not properly closes the button/dropdown. You can monitor those clicks (anywhere on the document) by:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    //check which element was clicked on
});
```

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I clarified my first comment on simbrisk's answer with another comment the next day.


I have not worked on that project in a few months but I would agree that using a click event handler on the document along with  simbrisk's code would have been a better solution than the hack I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

I did mine as shown below.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li id="theme_selector" class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Theme <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul id="theme" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Amelia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cerulean</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cyborg</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cosmo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Darkly</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Flatly</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Lumen</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Simplex</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Slate</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Spacelab</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Superhero</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">United</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Yeti</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Script

```
$('#theme li').click(function () {
   switch_style($(this).text());
        });
```

Works great