# Dropdown-menu on close callback

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I'm trying to execute a function if the dropdown-menu of bootstrap is closed. Surely I can just add the function call if the menu dropdown-toggle is click. But my concern is what if the user didn't click the dropdown-toggle but instead clicked outside or on other element. The dropdown-menu closes if I click on other element.

Is there a way or is there any callback on bootstrap if the dropdown-menu is closed?

I tried this but its not working

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    alert("Close");
});
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns-events hope this will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap: Call a js function when a dropdown is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479858/twitter-bootstrap-call-a-js-function-when-a-dropdown-is-closed)

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479858/twitter-bootstrap-call-a-js-function-when-a-dropdown-is-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this parameter:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    alert("Close");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find dropdown events over here
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#dropdowns-events

For quick help

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // your code goes here when dropdown closed
})
```

Comment: Both your's and @Max is correct but I like the approach of Hide rather than hidden so I'll be accepting this

Comment: For future readers is that the `hide` event triggers immediately the hiding is initiated, while `hidden` is triggered after all css transitions have executed (i.e. they represent the start and end of the hide process respectively)

Answer (score 0):

Struggle with this today and resolve it selecting the button id and not the menu class. I was using Bootstrap 5

```
$('#myDropdownBtnId').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    alert("Dropdown closed!!!");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4.x the button must be targeted (not the menu)

---

```
$('#dropdownS').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
 console.log("closed");
})
```

---

```
<div id="dropdownS" class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownStatus" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Status
 </button>
 <div id="statusList" class="dropdown-menu">
  ....
 </div>
</div>
```