# Bootstrap Select Dropdown on change open another Bootstrap Select Dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I have 2 bootstrap select picker. How i automatically open adjacent drop down when one drop down is selected.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" id="letterdropdownboxes1" name="letterdropdownboxes1">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" id="letterdropdownboxes2" name="letterdropdownboxes2">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="B1">B1</option>
</select>
```

I tried below code but not working.

```
$("#letterdropdownboxes1").on("change", function(e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if (valueSelected != null) {
        $('#letterdropdownboxes2').selectpicker('toggle');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479858/twitter-bootstrap-call-a-js-function-when-a-dropdown-is-closed

Answer (score 1):

You can do this `trick`, add `show` class to parent and siblings, then do a `refresh`

```js
$("#letterdropdownboxes1").on("change", function(e) {
  $('#letterdropdownboxes2').parent('.bootstrap-select').addClass('show')
  $('#letterdropdownboxes2').siblings('.dropdown-menu ').addClass('show')
  $('#letterdropdownboxes2').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.12/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" integrity="sha256-l3FykDBm9+58ZcJJtzcFvWjBZNJO40HmvebhpHXEhC0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.12/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha256-+o/X+QCcfTkES5MroTdNL5zrLNGb3i4dYdWPWuq6whY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" id="letterdropdownboxes1" name="letterdropdownboxes1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" id="letterdropdownboxes2" name="letterdropdownboxes2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="A1">A1</option>
  <option value="B1">B1</option>
</select>
```

**A note** *!*

*The right way to do this is `selectpicker('toggle')` but since you do a `click` event, on the same time it ignore `toggle` or `show`, kinda you close it before open it. to prove this, you can check and use this example:*

```js
$("#letterdropdownboxes1").on("change", function(e) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('#letterdropdownboxes2').selectpicker('toggle');
    }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.12/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" integrity="sha256-l3FykDBm9+58ZcJJtzcFvWjBZNJO40HmvebhpHXEhC0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.12/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha256-+o/X+QCcfTkES5MroTdNL5zrLNGb3i4dYdWPWuq6whY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" id="letterdropdownboxes1" name="letterdropdownboxes1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-size="10" id="letterdropdownboxes2" name="letterdropdownboxes2">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="A1">A1</option>
  <option value="B1">B1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you Pedram. $("#letterdropdownboxes1").on("change", function(e) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $('#letterdropdownboxes2').selectpicker('toggle');
    }, 500);
}); Second answer is working for me. Thank you.

Comment: Is it ok to add setTimeout from 500 to 10. It is fast opening. Any problem occur while loading?